# Re-load/initiate controller on event in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js

I have a controller as follows. It uses a d3 directive to draw a line graph and grabs data from a JSON request through a service.

```
myApp.controller('DownloadsLineCtrl', ['$scope', 'requestService', function($scope, requestService){
  $scope.title = 'Downloads over Time';
  $scope.tooltip = 'Test tooltip';
  requestService.getDownloadsLineData(global_m, global_y).then(function(data) {
        $scope.d3Data = data;
    });
}]);
```

I also have a reload control that should reload the controller when the variables `global_m` and `global_y` change.  How do I go about implementing this?  I'm not sure where to start... I'm coming from a JQuery mindset and having a difficult time Angularifying my brain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to reload your controller m8. $scope.$watch is what you need:

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watch)

Example:

```
$scope.$watch('global_m', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // global_m was changed, new value is 'newValue'
});
```

You have to declare $scope.global_m first, in order to use the $watch observer. You can do the same for the other variable you want to watch.

Comment: Cool!  Sorry, but is there a simple psuedocode example or reference you can link me to?  Not quite sure how to sync it all up.

Comment: Edited my answer with an example; you need to declare some variables on the $scope and you can watch them and run whatever you need when they change.